# Copy a wordpress site that I have no access to

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to copy a wordpress site which is live now to my own server. I have been asked to look after a site but the owner cannot get the password off the previous developer.

I can copy the file structure but if I paste the original file structure into my server then I will not be able to login.

Do I need to use the images and build the site from scratch?

Can I set up a new wordpress database and then just copy in the files that are live now.

Comment: Actually the database will be on the old developers server so I will have to create a new one. Looks like I will have to rebuild the site from scratch

Comment: I would contact the other developer.  Two sides to every story of course but presumably he isn't releasing the site as he hasn't been paid.  You might want to establish the likelihood that you are going to end up in the same boat.

Answer (score 2):

If you can access database via database management tool like PHPMyAdmin, you can change the password.

In the `wp_users` table, edit the user whose role is administrator and find the `user_password` column, change the function to `MD5` then set the value to the new password and save.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In wp_user table you can delete old password, and give new password you can choose select box Data Type MD5 format.

Answer (score 0):

Use [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/).

- Find admin ID: `wp user list --role=administrator`

If id = 123 and new password = 'password'

- Set password: `wp user update 123 --user_pass=password`